# AJAX photo uploader is submitting form multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm building a photo uploader with AJAX, which works, but the success message in the console appears 4 times for each upload, when it should only appear once.

Why does this code produce this behavior?

```
$('#image').change(function() { // this is the file input
    $('#imageForm').submit();
});
$('#imageForm').on('submit',(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: 'upload-photo.php",
        data:formData,
        cache:false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success:function(data){
            console.log("success");
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log("error");
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}));
```

Comment: I like the fact that it "words" :-).  Why is ContentType "false" ? Which object is FormData ? Perhaps its constructor also somehow performs this ajax call ?

Comment: check in network tab , it is posting data to server four times or only one time.

Comment: Can you post the exact code without modifiying it since I can see `url: 'upload-photo.php",` starts with single quote and ends with double quote?